# Print and for in 1 line Python 3.6.4

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I am making a passport and it was done.
But the file was 7kb big. That was too much for me.
So I started to make it shorter. I had a problem and this (look code below) is a simplified version of it but it didn't work. Can I do this for loop in the print command?

```
C = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G"]
print(C[N] for N in range(0,7))
```

---

```
Questions=["What's your last name?","What's your first name?","On what day are you born? (dd/mm/yyyy + hh:mm)","What's your place of birth?","What's your nationality?","What language(s) do you speak?","What's your sex? (W/M)"]
Data=[input(Questions[N]+"\n") for N in range(0,7)]
Keys = ["Last name","First name","Birthday","Birthplace","Nationality","Language(s)","Sex"]
for N in range(0,7):
    print(repr(N+1)+") "+Keys[N]+": "+Data[N])
```

(Above) Total First it asks you 7 question: (see 'Questions' list) it stores the answers in the list 'Data' and then it tells you what you typed. it shoud look like this (below)

```
What's your last name?
A
What's your first name?
B
On what day are you born? (dd/mm/yyyy + hh:mm)
C
What's your place of birth?
D
What's your nationality?
E
What language(s) do you speak?
G
What's your sex? (W/M)
H

1) Last name: A
2) First name: B
3) Birthday: C
4) Birthplace: D
5) Nationality: E
6) Language: G
7) Sex: H
```

Question: Can I do the code(below) in 1 line

```
for N in range(0,7):
    print(repr(N+1)+") "+Keys[N]+": "+Data[N])
```

`

Comment: `C[N] for N in range(0,7)` is a generator expression. What do you expect this to print? Try `print(''.join(C))` or `print(*C)`

Comment: The given description is not very helpful. Can you explain a bit more clearly as to what you are trying to achieve?